# Change whole application language using tap-i18n package

Tags: meteor

As per this site
https://github.com/TAPevents/tap-i18n/blob/master/README.md#quickstart

i have started with demo using tap-i18n package and it works fine.
Now
I want Convert application language when selecting language from drop-down list.

For that i have created one meteor application.
in that i have putted on drop-down list filled with different languages.

Now ,
when i select any language from drop-down list it should change whole application language using tap-i18n package.

it is possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

take a look to this example http://blog.digital-hosting.info/meteor-internationalisation/

header.html

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">Languages</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#" class="lang" data-lang="fr">Francais</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="lang" data-lang="en">English</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="lang" data-lang="zh">中文</a></li>          
  </ul>
</div>
```

header.coffee

```
Template.header.events = "click a.lang": (e) ->
  lang = 'undefined'
  $this = $(e.target)
  lang = $this.data("lang")
  TAPi18n.setLanguage lang
  return
```

Comment: Thanks, i have created that demo. now i want to change all application text to particular language without creating any language file. is it possible ? Currently it gets browser language but doesn't change language when i click on other language from drop-down list.

Comment: You have to create your international files in your i18n folder with one file per language to switch between languages.

Comment: so there is no other way without creating  one file per language to switch between languages?

Comment: That's the basic mechanism of internationalisation. I don't know if there's any other mechanism to do that.